# find letter in column vba

Tags: vba, object, if-statement

I have if function that should check a few conditions in excel tab and if column B <> 0 and column C has "A" then it gives me "OK"

But it is not working. I tried to add .text, .value or whatever, still it doesnot see "A" in and gives me "Run-time error 424 Object required"

Could you please advise?

```
    Sub test()

        Dim varSheetA As Variant
        Dim varSheetB As Variant
        Dim strRangeToCheck As String
        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim iCol As Long
            Dim iRow1 As Long
        Dim iCol1 As Long
            Dim jRow As Long
        Dim jCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

        strRangeToCheck = "A1:V1000"
        ' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
        Debug.Print Now
        varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
        varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
        Debug.Print Now

 For iRow1 = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol1 = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)

        If varSheetB(iRow1, 2) <> 0 And varSheetB(iRow1, 3)="A" Then
        MsgBox ("OK")

               'Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            'Cells(iRow1, iCol1).EntireRow.Copy
            'Sheets("Sheet4").Select
            'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            'ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
        Next iCol1
    Next iRow1


MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Cells` object when you work with cells like this: `If Cells(iRow1, 2) <> 0 And Cells(iRow1, 3) = "A" Then`. (It is not clear what you intend to do with varSheetA but this might help).

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing here when we can't see all of your code.

Comment: ^^ Please show more of your code

Comment: Updatedm added code

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: Does column C of sheet 2 have "A" in it for a same row as sheet 1 has <> 0 in column A? And do you really want  MsgBox ("OK") for every column on a row where there is a match?

Comment: Yes, column C have A and column A has numbers in it. For above code error is not ocurring and I dont have MsgBOX even if all conditions are ok, but if I change         If varSheetB(iRow1, 2) <> 0 And varSheetB(iRow1, 3)="A".VALUE then I have this error

Comment: I'm not sure why strRangeToCheck is set as `A1:V1000` if you only want to check columns B & C.  It would be faster to check one column, and if that meets the criteria then check the cell next to it to see if that also meets the criteria.

Comment: Your question says _column C_ and _Column B_, but your comment above says _column C_ and _Column A_.  Gotta be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is hard to follow, but your description says you want to look in column C for the letter A and if found check if the value in column B is not 0.

I'm pretty sure you don't want to display 'OK' everytime a value is matched - that could be 1000 oks to ok, which is not ok (unless you're building some kind of torture program).

This code will return a single message box listing the row numbers that matched the criteria.  No doubt you'll want to change the code to do something a bit more useful though.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FoundValue As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim Message As String

    'Only going to search column C for the letter A.
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C1000")

    With SearchRange
        'Find the first value if it exists.
        Set FoundValue = .Find("A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        'Only continue if something was found.
        If Not FoundValue Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = FoundValue.Address
            Do
                'Record the row number if the value in column B is not 0.
                If FoundValue.Offset(, -1) <> 0 Then

                    'Copy the row to Sheet2.
                    'Column C will have a value in each row (it will contain the letter A)
                    'so that can be used to find the next available row to copy to.
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        FoundValue.EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2)
                    End With

                    Message = Message & FoundValue.Row & vbCrLf
                End If

                'Look for the next letter A.
                Set FoundValue = .FindNext(FoundValue)

            Loop While FoundValue.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox "Criteria met on these rows:" & vbCrLf & Message, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. If I have in column A symbol "A" AND column B<>0 then I need to copy row with this symbol "A" and paste it in 2 tab

Comment: I've added the code to copy the value over to Sheet2.